# merge every two rows in one Sum multiple entries

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I am bit struggling with the output,as i need to merge every second row with first , sort and add up all the multiple entries.

sample output:

```
bittorrent_block(PCC)
127
default_384k(PCC)
28
default_384k(BWM)
28
bittorrent_block(PCC)
127
default_384k(PCC)
28
default_384k(BWM)
28
```

## Convert 2nd row into Column (expected)

```
bittorrent_block(PCC): 127
 default_384k(PCC):  28
 default_384k(BWM): 28
 bittorrent_block(PCC): 127
 default_384k(PCC):  28
 default_384k(BWM): 28
```

## Sum all duplicate entries  (expected)

```
bittorrent_block(PCC): 254
 default_384k(PCC): 56
 default_384k(BWM): 56
```

These are the possible piece of code I tried. what I am finally getting as

```
    zcat file.tar.gz | awk 'NR%2{v=$0;next;}{print $0,v}'
     bittorrent_block(PCC)
     default_384k(PCC)
     default_384k(BWM)
     default_mk1(PCC)
     default_mk1_10m(PCC)


zcat file.tar.gz |awk 'NR%2{ prev = $0; next }{ print prev, $0;}
 127orrent_block(PCC)
 28ault_384k(PCC)
 28ault_384k(BWM)
```

Due to this, I am not able, to sum up duplicate values.
Please help.

Comment: How is 127+127=245?

Comment: the output from your last set of code appears to show your file may contain dos/windows line endings (`\r\n`) ... notice the 1st line of output shows the `127` at the front of the line after overwriting the `tor` from the previous line ... this is an indication of the existence of the `\r` characters; net result is you'll also need to remove the `\r` character

Comment: please update the question to show/confirm the expected output; do you need the combined rows *AND* the summarized rows? and do they need to be provided in any specific order?

Comment: @markp-fuso : there is no specific order. the expected output is I need to sum all the duplicate entries

Comment: @knittl: sorry my bad, its 254. typo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often find it easier to transform the input first and then process it. `paste` helps to convert consecutive lines into columns; then summing the numbers with awk becomes trivial:

```
$ <input paste -sd'\t\n' | awk '{sum[$1] += $2}END{for(s in sum) print s": "sum[s]}'
bittorrent_block(PCC): 254
default_384k(PCC): 56
default_384k(BWM): 56
```

Comment: Thanks dear, you really saved my day. it really worked after removing CRLF and your piece of code

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you got CRLF in your file, so you'll have to strip them:

```bash
zcat file.tar.gz |
awk -F '\r' -v OFS=': ' '
    NR % 2 { id = $1; next }
    { sum[id] += $1 }
    END { for (id in sum) print id, sum[id] }
'
```

```
bittorrent_block(PCC): 254
default_384k(PCC): 56
default_384k(BWM): 56
```

Comment: Thanks dear, you really saved my day. it really worked after removing CRLF as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
zcat file | ruby -e '$<.read.split(/\R/).
    each_slice(2).
    each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = 0}) {
        |(k,v), h| h[k] = h[k]+v.to_i
    }.
    each{|k,v| puts "#{k}: #{v}"}'
```

By splitting on `\R` this automatically handles either DOS or Unix line endings.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed,sort and bash):

```
zcat file |
paste - - |
sort | 
uniq -c | 
sed -E 's/^ *(\S+) (.*)\t(\S+)/echo "\2 $((\1*\3))"/e'
```

Decompress file.

Join pairs of lines.

Sort.

Count duplicate lines.

Format and compute final sums.